# How does a dependently typed programming language cope with mutability?

Tags: type-systems

I have been investigating on the viability of a "normal" programming language with dependent types. Think for example in Java and add dependent types to it. One difficulty which I have found is that the type of a variable may change when mutated, like in the following piece of pseudo-code:

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3]; // The type of xs is List<int, 3>
let ys = [4, 5];    // The type of ys is List<int, 2>
xs.concat(ys);      // We concatenate the lists, so the type of xs is now List<int, 5>
```

This becomes a problem when we mutate a variable inside an `if` statement:

```
let xs = [1, 2, 3]; // The type of xs is List<int, 3>
if random_bool {
    xs.push(4);     // The type of xs is List<int, 4>
}
// The type of xs is unknown, because random_bool is set at runtime
```

Is there any research on this topic? Is it possible to address this issue without renouncing to mutability?

Comment: I see halting problems emerging

Comment: It depends on what you consider equality. If you mutate the object, but it doesn't change equality (say, due to reference semantics) then it removes much of the problems. Introduces others... But something to consider.

Comment: This problem is not particularly related to mutability. Consider `let xs = [3,2,1] in (if random_bool then 4:xs else xs)` in Haskell syntax.

Comment: @ratchetfreak You see correctly, but late. Regardless of mutability, checking dependent types (which is more akin to a proof assistant) is often technically undecidable, in the sense that the compiler may not terminate (or give up after some time). This is a well-known fact and doesn't diminish interest in dependent typing much.

Comment: This example is from the land of “don't do that”. Your problem is that the length of the list is part of the type, where you should be seeing a list as an opaque collection of zero or more elements. For a fixed-sized data structure such as C's arrays, the size is justifiably part of the type. There is actually a third option: the `xs` object has a dynamic concrete type such `List[int, 5]`, but the identifier `xs` has a static type constraint such as `List[int, x where x == 3 || x == 5]` – but that could make some proofs difficult to carry out for a type checker.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Dependently-typed languages are usually total. Non-terminating programs aren't allowed, therefore the HP doesn't present itself. All programs halt. (Sometimes the language is restricted in such a way that the compiler can always prove termination, some languages are richer but put the burden on the programmer to provide a termination proof to the compiler.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Answer posted by [gelisam](http://www.reddit.com/user/gelisam) on the [dependent_types](http://www.reddit.com/r/dependent_types/comments/2f6z34/stackexchange_how_does_a_dependently_typed/) subreddit***

There are two aspects to your question.

1. The type of a variable changes as it is mutated
2. Ambiguous type after a conditional block

An assignment which changes the type of the assigned variable is called a "strong update". If you really want your language to support those, be warned that tracking those type changes will make your type system much more complicated, because your type judgements will need to keep track of the code regions inside which your hypotheses and conclusions are valid.

One such type system is described in Stefan Monnier's paper [Statically tracking state with Typed Regions](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~monnier/tr.pdf). It's been a while since I have learned about this, but the paper seems to describe a language which has statements for strong update, and yet supports very powerful dependent types, namely the calculus of inductive constructions.

Given the kind of language you are trying to implement, however, you probably can't afford such an increase in your complexity budget. So here's a much simpler solution: use ordinary assignments instead of strong updates!

I think I understand why you think you need strong updates, but you probably don't. Consider the following Java snippet:

```
Parent p = new Child1();
p = new Child2();
if (condition) {
  p = new Child3();
}
```

The runtime type of `p` changes at each assignment, but since Java lacks strong updates, the compile-time type of `p` remains Parent. There is a tradeoff in the choice of `p`: a type such as `Child1` would have been more precise, and would have allowed more methods to be called on `p`, but would only allow future assignments to replace `p` with another value of type `Child1` or a subclass thereof. The type `Parent` allows more flexible assignments, but restricts the available methods to those of `Parent`.

Similarly, when choosing a type for a mutable variable `xs` in your dependently-typed language, users could have to choose between a precise type such as `ist<int,3>` and an imprecise type such as `Σ n:Nat. List<int, n>`, that is, a dependent pair indicating that the `int` part of `List<int,n>` is fixed but the `n` part can be changed by mutations.

With the former type, some methods would be available, such as those which require the list to be non-empty for example, while other methods would be unavailable, namely those which change the length of the list. With the latter type, only methods which work regardless of the current `n` could be called, but this time it would be legal to change the length of the list. In particular, it would be legal to change the length of the list inside a conditional block, because the code after the block is already unable to call methods which expect a particular length.

What I am trying to say is that adding mutability to a language with dependent types does not necessarily lead to also adding strong updates, and that a language with the first two features but not the third would be simpler and more familiar than a language with strong updates.

Comment: It's good that you correctly attributed the original author of that answer. However, it would be fair to make this post a “community wiki”, which means that any upvotes for this excellent answer will not give you reputation points for something you didn't write. To make a post community wiki, edit it and choose the “community wiki” checkbox below the text edit field.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I hadn't noticed that it was possible to do it.

Answer (score 3):

As [delnan said in comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255077/how-does-a-dependently-typed-programming-language-cope-with-mutability/255159#comment514577_255077), this has little to do with mutability. Let's see how one could type their example.

```
let xs = [3,2,1] in (if random_bool then 4:xs else xs)
```

In a dependently-typed language, `if-then-else` is a special case of `elimBool`, the eliminator for boolean-valued expressions whose type is:

```
elimBool :: (P : Bool -> Type) (t : P true) (f : P false) (b : Bool) -> P b
```

Indeed: if we take `P` a constant, we recover the typing principle for `if-then-else` modulo permutation of the arguments.

Now, in this instance we do not really have an `if-then-else` expression given that the two branches don't have the same type. We have a full-blown `elimBool` one. And it can be typed the following way:

Start by defining the appropriate predicate `Pred` describing the type of the expression:

```
Pred :: Bool -> Type
Pred b = elimBool (\ _ -> Type) List<int, 4> List<int, 3> b
```

or, equivalently given that `Pred`'s predicate is constant, we can use an `if-then-else` expression:

```
Pred :: Bool -> Type
Pred b = if b then List<int, 4> else List<int, 3> b
```

In other words, the predicate inspects its argument and says that it expects either a list of length 4 or one of length 3 depending on whether the argument is true or false.

The expression itself can then be written:

```
Exp :: Pred random_bool
Exp = elimBool Pred (4 : xs) xs random_bool
```

Indeed, according to `elimBool`'s type the first branch `4 : xs` has to have type `Pred true` which is precisely `List<int, 4>` whilst the second one has type `Pred false` which is equal to `List<int, 3>`.